# Ionic cordova build error runtime.aar

Tags: android, ionic3

have error when bulid android

Could not find runtime.aar (android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://jcenter.bintray.com/android/arch/lifecycle/runtime/1.1.0/runtime-1.1.0.aar

why get this error?

Comment: I use onesignal plugin for ionic, this plugin work with firebase, maybe is that issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by modifying the gradle.build like this:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
}}
```

And this:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
project.ext {
  defaultBuildToolsVersion="25.0.2" //String
  defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
  defaultTargetSdkVersion=26 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
  defaultCompileSdkVersion=26 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
}}
```

i just added "google()" before jcenter() statement.

Also, install Firebase for Ionic:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/firebase
```

I hope it helps you :)